# Select List with categories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This might seem rather simple, but how can I create a select list that is split into categories?

For example, maybe I want to have a select list that allows students to choose courses at a university.  I might want to split them by faculty, so that the courses are displayed according to their faculty.  The user should not be able to select the faculty from the list.

Something like:

(Science):
 - Physics
 - Chemistry

(Humanities):
 - Geography
 - Philosophy

(Arts):
 - Drama
 - Music

Where the only acceptable selection options would be "Physics", "Chemistry", "Geography", "Philosophy", "Drama" and "Music", but where the faculty names also appear in the list, just aren't options to select.

There doesn't appear to be a "child" element within a SelectListItem, so I'm wondering how to handle this, and I can't find anything at all online.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a tree view, rather than a list...

Comment: What type of application are you developing? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET...?

Comment: @Konamiman C# .NET MVC 4 web application

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this : http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/02/26/asp-net-mvc-extending-the-dropdownlist-to-show-the-items-grouped-by-a-category.aspx